# How to solve numerically this system of coupled differential equations

Tags: differential-equations, numerics

I am trying to solve this system of coupled differential equations,

```
NDSolve[{(4 Ωr[a[t]])/a[t] + 
Derivative[1][Ωr][a[t]] == 0, (3 Ωm[a[t]])/a[t] + Derivative[1][Ωm][a[t]] == 0, (2 Ωk[a[t]])/a[t] + 
Derivative[1][Ωk][a[t]] == 0, Derivative[1][Ωc][a[t]] == 0, Derivative[1][a][t]^2 == 4900 a[t]^2 (Ωc[a[t]] + Ωk[a[t]]/a[t]^2 + Ωm[a[t]]/a[t]^3 + Ωr[a[t]]/a[t]^4), Ωr[0] == 1/100000, Ωm[0] == 0.3, Ωk[0] == 1/1000, Ωc[0] == 0.69899, a[0] == 1/1000}, {Ωr[a[t]], Ωm[a[t]], Ωk[a[t]], Ωc[a[t]], a[t]}, {t,200}]
```

I have five variables $ \Omega r $: `Ωr[a[t]], Ωm[a[t]],Ωk[a[t]],Ωc[a[t]]` and `a[t]`, the initial conditions are given in the code.

The problem is when I run the code, it appears:

> NDSolve::ndode: The equations {True} are not differential equations or initial conditions in the dependent variables {a}.

Thank you!!! I really appreciate.

Comment: You have defined variables that are functions of another function of $t$, i.e. $\Omega(a(t))$. I think you need to rewrite these as just functions of $t$.

Comment: Do you mean to take derivate respective to $ a $ or $ t $? Maybe it is better to show the problem in a better form.

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/214539/how-to-solve-this-system-of-coupled-differential-equations-numerically

Comment: there is the code, thank you!!